# How to prevent object/array mutation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutability, angular, angular2-routing

I've been trying to debug weird issue and I've finally figured out why it's happening. Just not sure how to prevent it (; I have this function:

```
getInfo(id) {
  id = id || "zero";
  let i = routeDefinitions.findIndex(r => Boolean(r.name.toLowerCase().match(id)));
  // console.log(i) - works in plunker
  // but in my app sometimes returns -1...
  let current = routeDefinitions[i];
  let next = routeDefinitions[i + 1] ? routeDefinitions[i + 1] : false;
  let prev = routeDefinitions[i - 1] ? routeDefinitions[i - 1] : false;
  return { prev, current, next };
}
```

..it works perfectly in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hNOrWWeOdo6A77y7Vbj?p=preview), but in my app I use its return value to update app state (custom implementation of redux pattern). When I send return value through this function:

```
  private _update(_old, _new) {
    let newState = Object.keys(_new)
      .map(key => {
        if (_old[key] === undefined) {
          _old[key] = _new[key];
        } else if (typeof _new[key] === "object") {
          this._update(_old[key], _new[key]);
        } else {
          _old[key] = _new[key];
        }
        return _old;
      })
      .find(Boolean);

    return Object.assign({}, newState || _old);
  }
```

..`routeDefinitions` array is mutated and things start to break... I've tried couple of things:

```
let current = [...routeDefinitions][i];
// and:
return Object.assign({}, { prev, current, next });
```

..but it didn't work. How can I prevent mutatation of `routeDefinitions` array?

**EDIT**: I've managed to reproduce the error in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5h51M8n7yt27kwMfDeHw?p=preview)

Comment: You could use Object.freeze, but that might lead to other issues if one of the other methods expects it to be mutable. In that case best would be to send a copy.

Comment: Can you specify the error/issue you're getting, and a plnkr with  a reproduction of the same issue?

Comment: I'm getting `~.current.name` cannot get name of undefined (paraphrasing), when I add `if (i === -1) console.log(i, routeDefinitions.map(r => r.name));` in getInfo(), below `let i` I see that array is mutated. I'll try to update plunker and somehow include `_update()`, I'm fairly certain issue is there...

Comment: ...updated the question with [new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5h51M8n7yt27kwMfDeHw?p=preview) that has error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by modifying `_update()` like this:

```
  private _update2(_old, _new) {
    let newState = {}; 
    Object.keys(_new)
      .map(key => {
        if (_old[key] === undefined) {
          newState[key] = _new[key];
        } else if (typeof _new[key] === "object") {
          newState[key] = this._update2(_old[key], _new[key]);
        } else {
          newState[key] = _new[key];
        }
        return newState;
      })
      .find(Boolean);

    return Object.assign({}, _old, newState);
  }
```

I use `old state` just to check values, don't modify it until later when `_update()` is finished.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5h51M8n7yt27kwMfDeHw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

> routeDefinitions array is mutated and things start to break

If your function is truly:

```
getInfo(id) {
  id = id || "zero";
  let i = routeDefinitions.findIndex(r => Boolean(r.name.toLowerCase().match(id)));
  // console.log(i) - works in plunker
  // but in my app sometimes returns -1...
  let current = routeDefinitions[i];
  let next = routeDefinitions[i + 1] ? routeDefinitions[i + 1] : false;
  let prev = routeDefinitions[i - 1] ? routeDefinitions[i - 1] : false;
  return { prev, current, next };
}
```

Then `routeDefinitions` **is not mutated**.  Something else is mutating routeDefinitions.